# How to change the text placement on edge Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-node

Consider the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 35mm,
vertex/.style = {circle, draw, text width=4.4em, align=center},
every edge/.style = {-Straight Barb, draw, semithick}
                  ]
%
\node (B) [vertex]  {Facility $B$};
\node (C) [vertex, right=of B]  {Facility $C$};
\node (A) [vertex, above=of $(B.north)!0.5!(C.north)$] {Facility $A$};
%
\draw (A) edge [bend right,"$p_{AB}$"] (B);
\draw (B) edge [bend right,"$p_{BA}$"] (A);
%
\draw (A) edge [bend left,"$p_{AC}$"] (C);
\draw (C) edge [bend left,"$p_{CA}$"] (A);
\draw (C) edge [bend left,"$p_{CB}$"] (B);
%
\draw[transform canvas={yshift=+1ex}]  (B) edge ["$p_{BC}$"]  (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve:

- Make the placement of `P_AB` as that of `P_AC`.
- Make the placement of `P_CA` as that of `P_BA`.
- Prevent the edges `BA` and `CA` from crossing each other.
- The subscripts `AB`, `BA`, `CA`, etc. do not really appear to be subscripts. They appear to be on the same line as `p`. Is there a way to emphasize their subscript-ness, if you may?
- What is the easiest and most straightforward way of scaling this picture (with all its contents) up or down?

Comment: please have a look to see if the answer meets the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instruction `swap` or its shortness `'` push edge label on opposite edge side.

**Edit:**
Now are considered all sub questions ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 35mm,
vertex/.style = {circle, draw, text width=3.2em, align=center},
every edge/.style = {-Straight Barb, draw, semithick},
bend angle=15 % <---
                  ]
%
\node (B) [vertex]  {Facility $B$};
\node (C) [vertex, right=of B]  {Facility $C$};
\node (A) [vertex, above=of $(B.north)!0.5!(C.north)$] {Facility $A$};
%
\draw   (A) edge [bend right,"$p^{}_{AB}$" ']  (B)
        (B) edge [bend right,"$p^{}_{BA}$"]    (A) 
%
        (A) edge [bend left,"$p^{}_{AC}$"]     (C) 
        (C) edge [bend left,"$p^{}_{CA}$" ']   (A) 
        (C) edge [bend left,"$p^{}_{CB}$"]     (B)
%
        (B) edge [bend left,"$p^{}_{BC}$"]  (C); % <---
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hadn't realized how straightforward changing edge label to the opposite edge side is. Thank you. Are you able to give any feedback on the 3 remaining points I mentioned?

Comment: @Aziz, sorry, iI forgot on this. For push subscripts slightly down, try with adding empty superscripts like `"$p^{}_{CB}$`. The simple solution to avoid of the crossing bended arrows is to draw them staright. Is this acceptable to you?

Comment: @Aziz, see edited answer. Now are considered all your sub questions.

Answer (score 0):

the overlapping is now addressed -- the subscript issue is addressed

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, positioning, calc, arrows.meta, decorations.markings,quotes}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 35mm,
    vertex/.style = {circle, draw, text width=4.4em, align=center},
    every edge/.style = {-Straight Barb, draw, semithick}
    ]
    %
    \node (B) [vertex]  {Facility $B$};
    \node (C) [vertex, right=of B]  {Facility $C$};
    \node (A) [vertex, above=of $(B.north)!0.5!(C.north)$] {Facility $A$};
    %
    \draw (A) edge [bend right,"$\text{p}_\text{AB}$" '] (B);
    \draw (B.north east) edge [out=45,in=255,looseness=1.2,"$\text{p}_\text{BA}$"] (A);
    %
    \draw (A) edge [bend left,"$\text{p}_\text{AC}$"] (C);
    \draw (C.north west) edge [out=135,in=-75,looseness=1.2,"$\text{p}_\text{CA}$" '] (A);
    \draw (C) edge [bend left,"$\text{p}_\text{CB}$"] (B);
    %
    \draw[transform canvas={yshift=+1ex}]  (B) edge ["$\text{p}_\text{BC}$"]  (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```