# LaTeX code for this diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

What would be the LaTeX code for the diagram below?

I have attached my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray}\label{cdofNLalgebra}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \begin{array}{l}
        \begin{picture}(4,2.6)
            \put(1.4,2.3){$X$}
            \put(1.7,2.4){\vector(1,0){2.3}}
            \put(4.1,2.3){$Y$}
            \put(4.1,2.2){\vector(0, -1){1.8}}
            \put(4.2,1.2){$\pi_2$}
            \put(3.6,0.0){$G(T)$}
            \put(1.7,2.3){\vector(1,-1){2.0}}
            \put(2.3,1.2){$\pi_1$}
        \end{picture}
    \end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graphics]

Comment: similar -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566183/how-to-change-the-text-placement-on-edge-tikz/566191#566191

Comment: have a look at the answer below

Comment: What is wrong with the existing code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `tikz-cd`.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-cd} % if tikz is already loaded, you can also use \usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm]
        & G(T) \arrow{dl}[swap]{\pi_1} \arrow[leftrightarrow]{dr}{\pi_2} & \\
        X \arrow[rr] \arrow[ur, bend right=15,dashrightarrow] & & Y 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, the `\pi` have the subscripts. :-) It is not \pi2 but \pi_2.

Comment: @Sebastiano Ah, you're right. Didn't notice it, now fixed.

Comment: Hi, ah, do not worry. Your answer is very nice that the detail is like the cherry on the cake.

Answer (score 3):

Just a general example of doing such like drawings-- if you want you can increase the bend angle of the arrow in the preamble

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 35mm,
vertex/.style = {text width=3.2em, align=center},
every edge/.style = {-Straight Barb, draw, semithick},
bend angle=15 % <---
                  ]
%
\node (B) [vertex]  { $X$};
\node (C) [vertex, right=of B]  { $Y$};
\node (A) [vertex, above=of $(B.north)!0.5!(C.north)$] { $G(T)$};
%
\draw   (A) edge ["$\pi_1$" ']  (B)
        (B) edge [bend right, dashed]    (A) 
        (C) edge [<->, "$\pi_2$" ']   (A) 
        (B) edge []  (C); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to draw a commutative diagram of some sort. There are packages which make this quite easy, e.g. [diagxy](https://ctan.org/pkg/diagxy) or [xymatrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix).